# What is the name of draggable behavior on UIView iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, draggable

Most view in ios are draggable like in safari that I can drag and when I release it bounce back into it place. What does this behavior called any reference on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to implement [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

> The central notion of a UIScrollView
>   object (or, simply, a scroll view) is
>   that it is a view whose origin is
>   adjustable over the content view. It
>   clips the content to its frame, which
>   generally (but not necessarily)
>   coincides with that of the
>   application’s main window. A scroll
>   view tracks the movements of fingers
>   and adjusts the origin accordingly.
>   The view that is showing its content
>   “through” the scroll view draws that
>   portion of itself based on the new
>   origin, which is pinned to an offset
>   in the content view. The scroll view
>   itself does no drawing except for
>   displaying vertical and horizontal
>   scroll indicators. The scroll view
>   must know the size of the content view
>   so it knows when to stop scrolling; **by
>   default, it “bounces” back when
>   scrolling exceeds the bounds of the
>   content.**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're referring to functionality inherent in [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html), which bounces back into place when it is scrolled "too far".

Safari implements UIWebView which implements UIScrollView, which is why it scrolls.